# how to write a template function which sort map by value?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I want to write a function, which sort map container by value.(not key, for key, i think map have done it)

i want to make it template, so it can sort `map` and `unordered_map`. by value of `double` or `int` or `string`.

my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                              
template<typename T>
std::vector<typename T::value_type> sort_map(const T& m) {
  std::vector<typename T::value_type> v(m.begin(), m.end());
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const typename T::value_type& a, const typename T::value_type& b) { return a.second < b.second;});
  return v;
}

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<int, double> a = {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4,3}};
  auto  v = sort_map(a);
  for (auto & i : v) {
    cout << "a[" << i.first << "] = " << i.second << endl;
  }
}
```

I get a mess error code from my complier, which is such a mess, that i cant read.

but the error seems happens because i use the deleted `operator =` in pair.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 for key, yes. but i want to sort by values. i think it's possible

Comment: The `value_type` of `std::unordered_map<int, double>` is `std:pair<const int, double>` - note the `const`. This makes the type non-assignable, and so impossible to `std::sort`. `std::vector<std::pair<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type>> v(m.begin(), m.end());` might work.

Comment: Do you mean you want the map contents *ordered* by value instead of by key? Then you solve that by presenting an ordering function for the map itself.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The OP does not attempt to sort the map itself. They copy the contents into a `std::vector`, and sort that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i tried with no const, seems still complie failed

Comment: And what is the *actual* problem you try to solve? Why do you think you need to sort or order the map contents in a non-default way? Perhaps a map isn't the correct type of container for your underlying problem? This all seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: Have a look at [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `value_type` of `map` and `unordered_map` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, note that the 1st element is `const`, which makes the `vector` containing `std::pair<const Key, Value>` can't be copied.

You can change the type of `vector` to `std::vector<std::pair<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type>>`, .e.g

```
template<typename T>
auto sort_map(const T& m) {
  std::vector<std::pair<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type>> v(m.begin(), m.end());
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const typename T::value_type& a, const typename T::value_type& b) { return a.second < b.second;});
  return v;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6eAKZqKYg42LTC6i)